# Solidworks Macro find and replace on every drawing sheet

Tags: loops, replace, macros, find, solidworks

I have some background with VBA and I hate doing the same task 100's of times. I often have to make Solidworks drawings,these drawings are templates that are mostly just tables that I populate with data. There are 3 things that need to be changed on each sheet in the file (from sheet 3 to the last sheet). Normally I go into each sheet and do 3 find and replaces to change each sheet. then move on to the next sheet and repeat.

My plan was to have the code count the number of sheets, prompt the user for the first find/replace, replace that text on all sheets, then repeat for the 2nd replace, and again for the 3rd. I recorded a macro and added some code but I keep getting run-time errors (in code below). Every other macro I've recorded never gave me so many errors, if you can please help

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swmodel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swdraw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim Part As Object
Dim Otext As String
Dim Ntext As String
Dim Smax As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim swSheet As SldWorks.Sheet
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swmodel = swApp.ActiveDoc
 'Set swSheet = swdraw.GetCurrentSheet

Smax = instance.GetSheetCount() - 3   ' runtime 424 error here
Set swSheet = swdraw.GetCurrentSheet  ' runtime 91 error if i skip the line above

Otext = Application.InputBox("find this text")
Ntext = Application.InputBox("find this text")

For i = 1 To Smax

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
'--------------------Find and Replace Annotations--------------------
Set swUtil = swApp.GetAddInObject("Utilities.UtilitiesApp")
Set swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations = swUtil.FindReplaceAnnotations
longstatus = swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.InitPMPage()
'--------------------Block Recording--------------------
#If 0 Then
#End If
'--------------------UnBlock Recording------------------
swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.FindText = Otext
swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.ReplaceText = Ntext
swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.options = gtFraMatchCase
swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.AnnotationFilter = gtFraAllTypes
Part.ClearSelection2 True
Part.ClearSelection2 True
Part.ClearSelection2 True
Part.ClearSelection2 True
Part.ClearSelection2 True
longstatus = swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.ReplaceAll()
'--------------------Block Recording--------------------
#If 0 Then
#End If
'--------------------UnBlock Recording------------------
longstatus = swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.Close()
Part.SheetNext
Part.ViewZoomtofit2

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what is instance?  Doesn't appear to be declared.  swdraw is never declared either.

Comment: that was from another forum explaining how to get solidworks to count the the number of sheets in the drawing. in the example it was not defined just used.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.  It will popup a success window for each sheet however as that is how the SOLIDWORKS find replace utility works.

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swDrawingDoc As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim vSheetNames As Variant
Dim longstatus As Long

Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swDrawingDoc = swModel
    vSheetNames = swDrawingDoc.GetSheetNames
    Otext = InputBox("find this text")
    Ntext = InputBox("find this text")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vSheetNames)
        swDrawingDoc.ActivateSheet (vSheetNames(i))
        Set swUtil = swApp.GetAddInObject("Utilities.UtilitiesApp")
        Set swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations = swUtil.FindReplaceAnnotations
        longstatus = swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.InitPMPage()
        swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.FindText = Otext
        swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.ReplaceText = Ntext
        swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.Options = gtFraWholeWord
        swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.AnnotationFilter = gtFraAllTypes
        longstatus = swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.ReplaceAll()
        longstatus = swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations.Close()
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have it looking at only sheet 3 and onward here though

Comment: possibly just take the `For i = 0 To UBound(vSheetNames)` and change it to `For i = 2 To UBound(vSheetNames)` and wrap it around an if statement making sure there are more than 3 sheets

Comment: thanks Andrewk, however I am now getting runtime 91 on this line `Set swUtilFindReplaceAnnotations = swUtil.FindReplaceAnnotations`  I will keep digging but this is already a step in the right direction

Comment: What version of solidworks?  I used 2015 to test.  Also, make sure there is no Option Explicit in the code.  This will error with that set.

Comment: solidworks 2011 x64 . I don't believe there is an option explicit but I will double check and try again

Comment: I could only test back as far as 2014.  2011 is pretty old, also I am searching for the whole word.  If you want to search part, change the Options to something else.